# keep track on UIDs that have access to a particular document - documnet size limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": "interesting",
  "moredata": "interesting",
  "access" : [
      'uid1',
      'uid2',
      '...',
      'uid5000'
     ]
}
```

For any user logging in the tool I want do:

```
collection.where('access', 'array-contains', [uid])
```

But, the document-size limit is 1Mb. What do I do, when I have 50.000 users that might find this document interesting? Then I cannot store this much uids...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds similar to storing UIDs of users who have marked a particular blog post as favorite. I generally prefer creating a sub-collection for this. It looks like:

```
blogs > {blogID} > favorites > {userID}
```

"favorites" is a sub-collection (maybe 'allowed_users' in your case) containing a document with key as users' UIDs who have marked it as favorites. If you are using Client SDK then you can use Firestore security rules to handle accessing the documents.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /blogs/{blogID} {
      allow read: if request.auth != null && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/blogs/${blogID}/favorites/$(request.auth.uid))
    }
  }
}
```

This rules will allow users to read the blog only if their UID is present in that sub-collection. I usually store the timestamp of when user had marked the blog as favorite in those docs and some metadata if required.

Another way could be making a whole new collection (maybe called "accessess") which will contain documents with the following structure:

```
{
  blogID: "someBlogID",
  userID: "UserUID",
  addedAt: 1624176342872
}
```

This may not look well structured when compared to using sub-collections but benefit of doing so is you can query list of blogIDs user has marked as favorite (or has access to) with a simple query.

```
const userUID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

firebase.firestore().collection("accesses").where("userID", "==", userUID).get().then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(`User has access to ${snapshot.size} documents/blogs`)
})
```

Firestore security rules will take care of the access for you.

Comment: This is actually the way I went. It gives a challenge if I actually want to load all the documents at once (like a query).

Comment: Yes that's really convenient that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you think that number of users is realistic, you will have to store the UIDs as separate documents - for example in a subcollection. Looking up the main documents then becomes a two-step process:

1. Query the sub-collections (with a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query)).
2. Load each unique parent document from the results.

Alternatively, you can explicitly store the inverse relationship. So for each user, have a document (or subcollection) with the IDs of the documents that they have access to. In this scenario, getting those documents is a similar two-step process.

1. Load the IDs of the documents the user has access to.
2. Load those documents (uniqueness is already guaranteed here).

Comment: Check. Getting it 'in one call' seems not be possible. Yes  the amount of users *could* get into these numbers. Thanks for the tips, they make total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Do you *really* need to track *individual* access for 50,000 users - or do you *actually* have anywhere from 2 to 20 different *types* of access (admin, manager, user, guest, etc)?

Use a role-based access system.

Comment: It is actually the case that every individual user can have access to specific documents indeed.